# capture video from a built-in camera programatically

Tags: java, c++, c, video-capture

I was wandering how could capture video from the built-in camera of my netbook, under Linux, ubuntu. The programming language could is not an issue (but I prefer Java or the old school c)

Thanks in advance for your answers,
Gian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux the canonical way of talking to webcams are via [v4l](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Video4Linux).

Here is a library called [libfg](http://antonym.org/libfg/) for a simple high level C API on top of [v4l](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Video4Linux).

Answer (score 2):

You can look into OpenCV, for C/C++. It is very powerful.

Comment: Hey, I took a look over OpenCV and it looks a really big API, more for manipulating images. I just want to capture video from the built-in camera on my gateway netbook which after I would be streaming it over the internet

Comment: @gvalero87 OpenCV will do what you want, but from my experience using it in Windows instead of Linux is easier because you can use the EmguCV wrapper and develop in C#.

Comment: @typoknig Yeah I even found some other libraries for windows. The thing is that I specially need it for Linux

Comment: OpenCV can use v4l, so yes, OpenCV can be used for this purpose. If you don't need the rest of OpenCV, it can be overkill though.

Answer (score 1):

For Java check out the [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html). It hasn't been updated in some time, but can be used to capture video. I used it a while ago to write some teleconferencing type stuff.

Comment: yeah I got that but isn't it a problem that it hasn't been update for such a long time?

Comment: It was still out of development when I was using it and I didn't run into any problems. Everything I used worked properly and was well documented.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind using flash I would write it in flex, its very easy and you can write it to work on pretty much every Operating System (except ipad). You can use this code as a starting example: http://www.red5-recorder.com/

Also you can use red5 itself as a nice open source streaming server. You shouldnt need to buy anything for any of this, although much easier to code with flex builder, I think you can get a 60 day trial.

Comment: It says that is for "your website". Actually i don't need it for a website. I just want to capture from the built-in camera and stream over a socket. is red5 going to help me?

Comment: @gvalero87, I think not. Also, Flash is evil, didn't you get the memo? ;-)